# Socket.io cannot connect, resorts to "polling"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to create a websocket client-server app where client and server will run on two different instances.

### Setup

- Server/Back-end: running on `localhost:9006` with [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) including socket.io
- Client/Front-end: running on `localhost:9007` with [angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) + `socket.io-client` + btford.socket-io (a AngularJS socket.io bridge)

[image: Client and server]

### Server

**Note:** not complete code, but the pieces I think are relevant.

```
// ----- socketio.js -----

// When the user connects.. perform this
function onConnect(socket) {
    // When the client emits 'info', this listens and executes
    socket.on('info', function (data) {
        console.info('[%s] %s', socket.address, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        socket.emit('pong', 'OK!');
    });
    // Insert sockets below
    require('../api/thing/thing.socket').register(socket);
}

socketio.set('origins', 'http://localhost:9007');

// ----- express.js -----

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9007');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

// ----- app.js -----

// Start server
server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
});
```

### Client

```
// ----- client app.js

angular
.module('weldCommentsClientApp', [
    'ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngCookies', 'ngMessages', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch',
    'btford.socket-io'
])
.factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
    var myIoSocket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:9006');
    var mySocket = socketFactory({
        ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });
    mySocket.forward('pong');
    console.log('mySocket', mySocket);
    return mySocket;
})

// ----- client main.js

angular.module('weldCommentsClientApp').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, mySocket) {
    $scope.$on('socket:pong', function (ev, data) {
        console.log('socket:pong', ev, data);
    });
    mySocket.emit('info');
});
```

### Results

No console errors on server nor client, but it doesn't work and the server logs 100's of these lines:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1421488528935-16027 200 2ms
```

...which looks like the client connects over HTTP but fails to switch over to websockets.

Any ideas?

### Update

Here is the entire client/server project with instructions in README: https://github.com/weld-io/socket.io-client-server-boilerplate

Comment: The `socket.io` protocol starts with a request to negotiate what type of connection to use.  Can you show us the req/res for that?

Comment: What version of socket.io are you using?

Comment: Some antivirus software tend to mess up with websockets. Try disabling the antivirus or run over https.

Comment: Did you try by removing the restriction.. 
`socketio.set('origins', 'http://localhost:9007')`

Comment: try to change `$scope.$on('socket:pong'` to `$scope.$on('pong'`

Comment: @VinayK tried this, no difference. See source code: https://github.com/weld-io/socket.io-client-server-boilerplate

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The path is not defined correctly in server/app.js

Try to use '/socket.io' path like this:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
  serveClient: (config.env === 'production') ? false : true,
  path: '/socket.io'
});
```

Next, to choose websockets instead of long-polling, you can select the websocket transport in test-client/scripts/application.js

```
var myIoSocket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:9006', {transports:['websocket']});
```

Comment: Holy, I think your first suggestion fixed it (the second one generated another error). Let me just test it more.

Comment: Hi there, i think specifying 'websocket' as a transport drains battery, and causes to overuse cpu, since my device is heating up whenever i run my application. But as far as i experienced lately, setting 'websocket' is the only way to use socket.io on Heroku. @leszek.hanusz

Comment: This works, but why? Specifically all I did was add the transports and it began working properly. It seems like sock.io should default to using websockets instead of polling.

Comment: @Justin. "Specifically all I did was add the transports and it began working properly"

I think this bug has resurfaced ...
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/219#issuecomment-177882354

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you test client-server respectively. nc will be an ideal alternative for this kind of situation.

1. start server and `echo testserver | nc server_ip server_port` and check server log.
2. start client and `netcat -l -p server_port` and check client log.

BTW, the client code you've showed doesn't seem to attempt to connect to the server.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't `var myIoSocket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:9006');` the connection statement?

Comment: @TomSöderlund Then this is the catch. You have mentioned that your server listened on 9007.

Comment: @TomSöderlund I guess you misunderstood ports and instances. Just briefly say, the port is where you receive data from and send data to, that is how it works. And it has nothing to do with instances.

Comment: Ah, interesting! So what should I change in my code above? If I run both on `localhost:9006`, that would break either the client or server, right?

Comment: @TomSöderlund That will connect the client and server and break neither of them.

Comment: This happens `Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Fatal error: Port 9006 is already in use by another process.`

Comment: See new image to illustrate, above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your server are using sockets on http://localhost:9007 and your client on http://localhost:9006. Try to put both on the same port, it should work.

Comment: You missed the "where client and server will run on two different instances" part of my question, I think.

Comment: See new image to illustrate, above.

Answer (score 0):

Could try 2 things:
first change

```
window.io.connect('http://...
```

to

```
window.io.connect('ws://...
```

Secondly on server side set

```
socketio.set('transports',['xhr-polling']);
```

I know that looks incorrect, since you want to avoid polling, still it helped a lot of people who had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! Tried it, didn't work. Source code: https://github.com/weld-io/socket.io-client-server-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but maybe this'll help someone.

If you are using reverse proxy on nginx, you'll need additional proxy_http_version, proxy_set_header(s) in your server nginx block.

```
# example ssl nginx block
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888; # your server port
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Origin $http_origin;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    }
}
```