# socket.io WebSocket connection failed

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io to connect to [a different domain](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/#from-a-different-domain), and it can successfully connect using [polling](https://socket.io/docs/v4/how-it-works/#http-long-polling), however when attempting to connect using websockets gets the error "WebSocket connection to 'wss://XXXXX' failed".

After observing the network activity the server seems to indicate that it is capable of upgrading to a websocket connection (although I won't claim to be an expert in understanding these requests), but isn't able to do so:

[image: the network activity the server seems to indicate that it is capable of upgrading to a websocket connection]

[image: console shows that its not able to make websocket connection]

I'm just trying to produce a minimal viable product right now so here is my node.js server code:

```
let http = require('http');
let https = require('https');
let fs = require('fs'); 
let express = require('express');

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('XXXXXXXXX', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('XXXXXXXXX', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('XXXXXXXXX', 'utf8');

const options = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

let app = express();

let httpsServer = https.createServer(options,app);
let io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: true
    }
});
httpsServer.listen(443);

console.log('starting');

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("something is happening right now")

    socket.on("salutations", data => {
        console.log(`you are now connected via ${socket.conn.transport.name}`);
        socket.emit("greetings", "I am the socket confirming that we are now connected");
    });
});
```

Client-side JavaScript:

```
const socket = io("https://XXXXXXX");
console.log(socket);

socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("now connected");

    socket.on("message", data => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on("greetings", (elem) => {
        console.log(elem);
    });
});

let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
h1.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log("I am now doing something");
    socket.emit("salutations", "Hello!");
})
```

The only suggestion [in the official documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#problem-the-socket-is-stuck-in-http-long-polling) for this issue isn't relevant because I'm not using a proxy, and [other suggested fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998407/socket-io-cannot-connect-resorts-to-polling) result in no connection at all (presumably because they prevent it from falling back to polling)

EDIT: also if it helps narrow down the problem, when querying my server using https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester it results in "Connection failed, see your browser's developer console for reason and error code"

Comment: did you resolved it ?

Comment: no, although long polling appears to work fine

Comment: hi. any update? I just run in this exact problem :((

Comment: no, I'm sticking with long polling for now

Comment: try to add {path: "/socket"} in your config on the server and client