# Can't connect error in socket.io's websocket link

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've set up socket.io correctly. I'm not sure why when socket.io sends a request to `wss://[my domain]/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=uNSCkuO8YeCLFOnEAAAC`, it returns this error:
[image: Error]

I've double-checked everything. Going to `/socket.io/socket.io.js` shows the client bundle correctly. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70633932/socket-io-websocket-connection-failed#comment131413695_70633932) comment, I put the path as /socket in both client and server, which did not fix it.

Client-side code:

```html
<script type="module">
  import { io } from "https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.2/socket.io.esm.min.js";
  const socket = io("https://[my domain]", {
    path: "/socket",
  });
  const chatbox = document.getElementById("chat-box");
  socket.on("send-livechat-msg", (e) => {
    // some code that doesn't matter...
  });
</script>
```

Server-side code:

```js
import http from "node:http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  path: "/socket",
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("send-livechat-msg", (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
io.attach(server);

// and later on in the code...
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "iceutils",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn -p typescript tsc",
    "start": "rimraf ./dist && yarn build && node --no-warnings dist/index.js",
    "lint": "yarn eslint src --ext .ts --fix",
    "pretty": "npx prettier -w ./src"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.20",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.9",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.14",
    "@types/passport-discord": "^0.1.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "yarn-upgrade-all": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@maxmind/geoip2-node": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/common-tags": "^1.8.3",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.15",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.3.3",
    "@types/ms": "^0.7.33",
    "@types/passport-oauth2-refresh": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/stripe": "^8.0.417",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "common-tags": "^1.8.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cron": "^3.1.6",
    "discord-html-transcripts": "^3.2.0",
    "discord.js": "^14.13.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "ejs-lint": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-cors": "^0.0.3",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "hcaptcha": "^0.1.1",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.6.3",
    "ms": "^2.1.3",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-discord": "^0.1.4",
    "passport-oauth2-refresh": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "stripe": "^14.2.0",
    "winston": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably need no / after .io

Comment: @folibis, the url is not controlled by me, it is controlled by socket.io

Comment: add the `package.json` file to your question.

Comment: @xgqfrms there, done

Comment: Try to create a minimal runnable demo project. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http, this package is too old, I think you should use  the`node:http` module.

Comment: You should add the imported modules in your `Server-side` code.

Comment: @xgqfrms the question has been updated, and about the reproducible, it is working fine in localhost with pretty much the same code. I'm not sure if its a firewall issue or anything, because I'm running an oracle cloud server with ufw and iptables completely turned off, along with the oracle subnet rules set so that any requests can get through. It is visible that it is working as /socket.io/socket.io.js is visible from external networks and socket.io is able to identify the socket server correctly, it is just failing at the websocket connection

Comment: And if this helps, I'm running a docker container and the subdomain is through nginx reverse proxy which I've set up properly with the help of the socket.io [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/reverse-proxy/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255817/discussion-between-mallusr-greatv2-and-xgqfrms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here is a quick fix solution

1. use `HTTPS` or `HTTP` on both of server-side and client-side

```js
import { io } from "https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.2/socket.io.esm.min.js";
// HTTPS ✅
const socket = io("https://[my domain]", {
  path: "/socket",
});
```

2. when using `HTTPS` protocol, make sure that your `PORT` is 443
3. you should choose to use only one way to bind the `server` to `io`, either `new Server(server)` or `io.attach(server)`

```js
// HTTPS ✅
import https from "node:https";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import express from "express";

const app = express();
// config SSL certificate 
// const options = {
//   key: fs.readFileSync('./your_domian.key'),
//   cert: fs.readFileSync('./your_domian.crt'),
// };
// const server = https.createServer(options, app);
// HTTPS ✅
const server = https.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  path: "/socket",
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("send-livechat-msg", (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
// io.attach(server);

// HTTPS port 443 ✅
const port = process.env.PORT || 443;
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

> Notice: you need config SSL certificate for `HTTPS` server

### my local `HTTP` demo screenshot

[image]

### refs

https://socket.io/docs/v4/#what-socketio-is-not

https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#the-request-path-does-not-match-on-both-sides